# Change key of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have following array as response from db. I am trying to convert this database response into multidimensional array as per my requirement.

```
       Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => C10359
                    [AE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 89785
                            [1] => 89786
                            [2] => 89857
                            [3] => 89859
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => C10428
                    [AE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 50191
                            [1] => 50203
                            [2] => 50230
                            [3] => 50244
                        )

                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => C10350
                    [AE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 89785
                            [1] => 89786
                            [2] => 89857
                            [3] => 89859
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => C10430
                    [AE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 50191
                            [1] => 50203
                            [2] => 50230
                            [3] => 50244
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Now I need to convert above array in following way.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [C10359] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 89785
                    [1] => 89786
                    [2] => 89857
                    [3] => 89859
                )
            [C10428] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50191
                    [1] => 50203
                    [2] => 50230
                    [3] => 50244
                )   
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [C10350] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 89785
                    [1] => 89786
                    [2] => 89857
                    [3] => 89859
                )
            [C10430] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50191
                    [1] => 50203
                    [2] => 50230
                    [3] => 50244
                )   
        )
)
```

following is way i am trying

```
array_map(function($arr) {
       return $arr[0] ; 
    },$panel_result);
```

But it is not working.

Kindly suggest how can I convert in required formate.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in order to get your array into the desired foramt, SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: I tried to do using array_map function but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick :

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        array(
            '_id' => 'C10359',
            'AE' => array
            (
                89785,
                89786,
                89857,
                89859,
            ),
        ),
        array(
            '_id' => 'C10428',
            'AE' => array
            (
                50191,
                50203,
                50230,
                50244,
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $levelK => $level) {
    if(!isset($output[$levelK])){
        $output[$levelK] = array();
    }

    foreach ($level as $subLevel) {
        $id = $subLevel['_id'];

        if (!isset($output[$levelK][$id])) {
            $output[$levelK][$id] = array();
        }

        foreach ($subLevel['AE'] as $val) {
            $output[$levelK][$id][] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unnecessary two foreach.

Comment: @Anant, I would probably have had done it differently if I had more info about the structure of OP's array. Not having this info, I just wanted to provide a simple and working example matching the data provided.

Comment: @vincenth i am getting dynamic arrayas a response. I have updated array in question

Comment: This is not working. kindly suggest some other way to do it

Comment: @Amit Could you provide a bit more info about what's not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and pass third param as the index key.

```
$reqArray = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $innerArray) {
  $reqArray[] = array_column($innerArray, 'AE', '_id');
}
```

OR

Use [`array map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$reqArray = array_map(function($a){
 return array_column($a, 'AE', '_id');
},$arr);
```

Comment: I have added array_map also in your answer as OP has tried that way.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, but that could be added as a separate one too(as it uses different array function).

Comment: No need it Bro. Centralize logic is the same :)